# Linking subdomain on bigrock to Amazon EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, subdomain, amazon-route53

I have a domain name hosted on `bigrock.in` pointed to an Amazon EC2 instance using Route 53. The four nameservers generated are placed in bigrock and it is working fine.

Now I have created a subdomain of the domain in `bigrock` and I want it to point to my application in another EC2 instance in another AWS account. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes.** The AWS account that is currently controlling your domain name with Route 53 must be used, but it can be pointed to anything on the Internet.

Steps:

- In the AWS account with the "other" EC2 instance, create an **Elastic IP Address** and assign it to the EC2 instance. This will ensure that its IP address does not change when the instance is stopped and started.
- In your existing Route 53 configuration (in the original account), **create a Record Set** for the sub-domain (eg `images.example.com`) of type `A` and enter the Elastic IP Address as the *value*.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have set the nameserver for your domain to point to Route53, you no longer need to control the subdomains from bigrock services. Just add them to your Route53 dashboard, and they'll be reflected live.